# Eclipse Neon - upload files to server via SFTP

Tags: eclipse, ssh, ftp, sftp

I'm using Eclipse Neon and Pydev and I'm not able to find a plugin or procedure to upload files edited within my machine to a remote server via SFTP.

I tried with JCraft but it seems to be not compatible with my Eclipse, since I get the error

```
  Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: SFTP Plug-in 0.0.4 (com.jcraft.eclipse.sftp.feature.feature.group 0.0.4)
  Missing requirement: SFTP Plug-in 0.0.4 (com.jcraft.eclipse.sftp.feature.feature.group 0.0.4) requires 'org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility 0.0.0' but it could not be found
```

(if someone knows how to solve this issue it would be amazing!)

Does anyone know how to make this possible? Maybe with remote system view or team synchronization tool? I haven't found a way to setup properly a project to obtain what I want..

Comment: The JCraft code is trying to use old Eclipse code (`org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility`) which is no longer in current releases of Eclipse.

Comment: No existing workaround?

Comment: Have you tried using Remote System Explorer (RSE)? What results did you get?